# How can I get xdebug to use the right page in vim while debugging a CodeIgniter app?

Tags: php, codeigniter, vim, xdebug

I have an Codeigniter app that I am trying to debug with vim.  I have xdebug installed on my server and I am using the xdebug helper extension for chrome.  The issue occurs when I initiate a debug session in vim with f5 and load the page I want to debug in chrome.  Vim always outputs the index.php page of my app instead of the page I loaded in chrome.  I don't understand what is happening.  Any help would be appreciated.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All requests to a Codeigniter site start with a call to Index.php. This file is responsible for bootstrapping the framework and ultimately routing the request to the correct controller.

My guess is that there is a setting somewhere that has xdebug stopping on the first line of executed code - line 1 of Index.php. I'm not familiar with VIM so cannot tell you where to find or how to change this setting.

You will need to set a breakpoint somewhere in the file you want to debug. In other words, in the controller that the URL is going to run.

Comment: I put a breakpoint in the controller.  Re-ran the debug session and it still stops at line 1 of index.php UNTIL you hit <f9>.  Awesome!

Comment: Being curious I found out how to prevent VIM from stopping on the first line. Add `g:vdebug_options["break_on_open"]=0` to the VIM configuration file `vimrc`.  [vimrc Info here](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Open_vimrc_file)

Comment: `Pattern not found:  vdebug_options["break_on_open"]=0`

Comment: You need to add that line to the file. It is not there by default.

Comment: I did add the line verbatim.  This error occurs after I start vim from the command line.

Comment: [Here is where](http://thorpesystems.com/blog/debugging-php-in-vim/) I found that command. I failed to realize that the command relies on a VIM plugin called [vdebug](https://github.com/joonty/vdebug). Sorry about that. As I said, I'm not a VIM user.

Comment: I was able to override the "break on open" option by changing the option in ~/.vim/bundle/vdebug/plugin. the option to change is `let g:vdebug_options_defaults = { "break_on_open" } : 0, Now xdebug bypasses the index.php file and starts at any arbitrary breakpoint I set.